# hyperlink a text shown in vf page leads to record detail page

Tags: apex, visualforce, record, hyperlink

I have below line from apex class that fails to redirect to a record detail page in a new tab. Can someone point out my error and suggest me a resolution please?

**Apex class snippet**

```
String AccountLinksString = '<br/><a href="/' + acs.AccountId + '">View Account Details</a> <a href="/apex/Edit_Account_DCR_vod?scontrolCaching=1&id=' + acs.AccountId + '">Create Data Change Request</a>';
```

Comment: for new tab i think you need to add  target equals to `_blank` in your anchor tag

Comment: Yes earlier it was not working. Target word was coming up in URL and was saying "URL No Longer exist" So removed it to get exact functionality.

Comment: have you tried like this `String AccountLinksString = '<br/><a target="_blank" href="/' + acs.AccountId + '">View Account Details</a> <a href="/apex/Edit_Account_DCR_vod?scontrolCaching=1&id=' + acs.AccountId + '">Create Data Change Request</a>';` ?

Comment: Thanks Ratan ! I was keeping href before target section. That's why it was not working! Thanks!

Comment: Please put it as correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to target attribute here in order to open the link in new tab

```
String AccountLinksString = '<br/><a target="_blank" href="/' + acs.AccountId + '">View Account Details</a> <a href="/apex/Edit_Account_DCR_vod?scontrolCaching=1&id=' + acs.AccountId + '">Create Data Change Request</a>';
```